# Laravel 4.1 Model Settings Not Being read

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

After updating to Laravel 4.1, I have been having issues with my Model files.

I have a model, **ClubEvents**, with the following settings:

```
class ClubEvent extends Eloquent {
  protected $table = "events";
  protected $primarykey = 'eventID';
  public $timestamps = true;
  protected $softDelete = true;
}
```

However, when using Eloquent commands such as

```
ClubEvent::find($id)
```

I receive an error that results from the query looking for an "id" column, not the defined "eventID" column.

Is there a missing update I'm looking over or is my laravel 4.1 update corrupted?

Comment: I think `$primarykey` should be camelCased. Try `$primaryKey` instead that should work.

Comment: I think that might have been it. HOWEVER: When I first made my laravel project, I accidentally made a model called Event.php (which I guess is reserved by Laravel core?). Now when I delete Event.php (but have the same model contents in another file, i.e. ClubEvent.php), I get model errors. I still can't figure out why this is...